# navigationcontroller causing app to crash

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have added navigation controller into my appication in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions like this

```
LoginViewController *mainView = [[[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mainView]autorelease];
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

And in my LoginViewController's viewDidLoad i have,

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
[super viewDidLoad];

UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] init];
img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar.png"];
bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];
[bar setBackgroundImage:img forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

UIImage *signIn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"signin_btn.png"];
UIButton *phButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[phButton setImage:signIn forState:UIControlStateNormal];
phButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, signIn.size.width, signIn.size.height);
UIBarButtonItem *phBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:phButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = phBarButtonItem;
[phButton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkConnection) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[phButton release];
```

When i run the app in my phone it crashes. When i remove the navigationcontroller from the appDelagate it works... Y cant i get my navigation to work properly and how can i avaoid it from getting crashed.

Comment: please add error you get in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code

try this code
Declare appdelete.h file

```
@class LoginViewController;  

LoginViewController *viewController; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet LoginViewController *viewController;
```

appdelegate.m file   declare

```
@synthesize viewController;
```

in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[window addSubview:nav.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;

  -(void) dealloc
 {
 [viewController release]; 
 ......//some code
 }
```

Comment: It works on iPhone Simulator the first time when i run the app. In the phone it crashes..

Comment: did you created LoginViewController class and xib file?

Comment: yes...its showing the nav bar and button in my phone now...but when i add a background image to the nav bar..thats causing theproblem

Comment: you want to change button background image or only change  Navigation bar background image? which u want to change?

Comment: You want to change background image for Navigation bar. add this code to your LoginViewController.m file - implementation LoginViewController (CustomImage)     (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"signin_btn.png"];
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

Comment: Found this code which works on iOS5 and iOS4     if ([navBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)])
    {
        [navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar-bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
    else
    {UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[navBar viewWithTag:NBarImgTag];
        if (imageView == nil)
        {imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar-bg.png"]];
            [imageView setTag:NBarImgTag];
            [navBar insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
            [imageView release];}}..thanks RK

Answer (score 0):

I this this cause crash.

```
[phButton release];
```

`phButton` does not need to be released;

By the way,

`phBarButtonItem` need to be released;

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your autorelease with navigation controller.

1. you try removing `autorelease` or

> navigationController = [[UINavigationController
>   alloc]initWithRootViewController:mainView];

1. try using property (if you have),

> self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController
>   alloc]initWithRootViewController:mainView]autorelease];

Comment: @user1168699. You remove all code from your viewDidload of mainview. May be some thind in mainview didLoad causes the problem.

Comment: Found out that when i'm trying to set the background image for the nav bar it crashes..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

instead of `[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];`

Comment: @user1168699: I think this must work fine because I have implemented the same concept and for me it works fine....check ur initWithNibName:@""...have u given it same as .xib name??

Comment: .xib is right...everytime i run the app on the simulator i have to to a reset. then only it works...but on the phone it doesn't work at all...when i remove the navigation bar, then it works fine

Comment: @user1168699: So the BEST way to know where exactly ur app crashes is to put break points. Put it in AppDelegate and in viewDidLoad of LoginViewController class.

Comment: Found out that when i'm trying to set the background image for the nav bar it crashes..

Comment: That's what I wanted to tell u....accept this if it is fruitful to u so other user can be in right way..:)

Answer (score 0):

[phButton release]; remove that line &

**img** & **phBarButtonItem** needs to be released

Comment: Did release them...nothing happens

Comment: set breakpoint in viewDidLoad function.Find where the app exactly crash or enabled NSZombie to trace the crash

Comment: Found out that when i'm trying to set the background image for the nav bar it crashes..